# Ordered list inside a textarea (Line number)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to implement text area with ordered list text. I have done but line number must be **incremented** only after **enter key pressed.**

Here is my effort: **[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFLAs/)**

Code

```
var lineObjOffsetTop = 2;
createTextAreaWithLines('codeTextarea');
function createTextAreaWithLines(id)
{
var el = document.createElement('DIV');
var ta = document.getElementById(id);
ta.parentNode.insertBefore(el,ta);
el.appendChild(ta);

el.className='textAreaWithLines';
el.style.width = (ta.offsetWidth + 30) + 'px';
ta.style.position = 'absolute';
ta.style.left = '30px';
el.style.height = (ta.offsetHeight + 2) + 'px';
el.style.overflow='hidden';
el.style.position = 'relative';
el.style.width = (ta.offsetWidth + 30) + 'px';
var lineObj = document.createElement('DIV');
lineObj.style.position = 'absolute';
lineObj.style.top = lineObjOffsetTop + 'px';
lineObj.style.left = '0px';
lineObj.style.width = '27px';
el.insertBefore(lineObj,ta);
lineObj.style.textAlign = 'right';
lineObj.className='lineObj';
var string = '';
for(var no=1;no<200;no++){
if(string.length>0)string = string + '<br>';
string = string + no;
}

ta.onkeydown = function() { positionLineObj(lineObj,ta); };
ta.onmousedown = function() { positionLineObj(lineObj,ta); };
ta.onscroll = function() { positionLineObj(lineObj,ta); };
ta.onblur = function() { positionLineObj(lineObj,ta); };
ta.onfocus = function() { positionLineObj(lineObj,ta); };
ta.onmouseover = function() { positionLineObj(lineObj,ta); };
lineObj.innerHTML = string;
}

function positionLineObj(obj,ta)
{
obj.style.top = (ta.scrollTop * -1 + lineObjOffsetTop) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: probably don't reinvent the wheel and use something powerful like YUI: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/editor/

Comment: I have edited my question. Please consider reopening.

Comment: I have done an rnd and posted the need again as

Answer (score 2):

Instead of working with a text area like that, you may want to use the contenteditable tag.

Here's an example of what that may look like.

HTML:

```
<div class="orderedList" contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var yourContent = "<ol><li>Go to home.</li><li>I need to installl window 8 and sql server 2012 by tommorow so that i can work with my project well and Need to clarify.</li><li>Test application.</li></ol>";

$('.orderedList').html(yourContent);
```

Then you could use some JQuery trickery to submit it with the form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but i need when typing the text in textarea and when press enter the new line number should be automatically added. I have tried but I can't do for paragrah type.